# UMVUE for $E(y^2)$ in Poisson distribution

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution, umvue

If $Y \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$. How do I find the UMVUE for $E(y^2)$?

I know that $E(y^2)$ is $\lambda$+$\lambda^2$, since I want to use Rao-blackwell thereom, I need a complete sufficient estimate for $\lambda$+$\lambda^2$, can I just use $\bar{y}$ as the complete sufficient statistic?

If not, what should I do? thank you!

Comment: Thank you for adding the `[self-study]` tag. Please read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Hint: think of the variance of the Poisson distribution.

Comment: You need to say some things about properties of complete sufficient statistics ... what do you know?

Comment: @Glen_b I think I have got this problem solved. The point I get stuck is that I don't have a sense that once I construct an unbiased estimator with complete sufficient statistic, I already get an UMVUE. The way I am familiar with is to calculate E(unbiased estimator|complete sufficient statistic) that stops me from getting an answer. As Johnk said I can construct this estimator directly. Thanks!

Comment: sounds like you got to the correct answer. You could post it.